# Return fractional period

Tags: c#, recursion, fractions

1 - constant, n - int number. I always share 1/n

Examples:

1. 1/n (n = 3), 1/3 = 0,333333, so period of this number is (3).
2. 1/n (n = 7), 1/7 = 0,1428571428571429, period of this number is
   (1428571).
3. 1/n (n = 2), 1/2 = 0,5 , so this number doesnt have period.

So i need to wrote recursive algorithm, which print or return period. I tried my algorithm, but get inccorect result incorrect result in some cases.

```
using System;

namespace LB_5._2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter number: ");
            int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());            
            GetPeriod(n);
        }
        public static void GetPeriod(int n, int current = 10, int part = 0, string result = "", int next = 0)
        {
            part = current / n;
            string currentCheck = part.ToString();
            result += part;
            next = (current - n * part);                       
            if(result.Contains(((next * 10) / n).ToString()))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
            else
            {
                GetPeriod(n, next * 10, part, result);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: *"For example, if i try 1/6"* how are you *trying* that? You're typing in the console `1 / 6` ?

Comment: Using 1/6 as an input, a System.FormatException is thrown.

Comment: what does the progam do and what is the desired output?  why do you use recursion

Comment: @Cid 1 its a constant, and you wrote number by which to divide the constant. So input its - n, and we check 1/n

Comment: @GoldenLion if you share 1/19, you got result 0,0526315789473684. It consist repeating numbers, but not consist period. Thats what i mean

Comment: a period is defined as nn one with n occurring one or more time after nn

Comment: Please give a more thorough description of what you expect here and why, preferably with some good examples. It isn't clear why you're expecting 1/6 to become 6, given that your program already is know to not do what you want it to do. If the code is incorrect, all we can fall back on is your description and there is none. Please rectify this. Also, you're inputting an integer, so please describe what you mean by trying 1/6. Please post a [mcve]

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Okay, so i always share 1/n (n - int)
Examples: 1/n (n = 3), 1/3 = 0,333333, so period of this number is (3).
1/n ( n = 7), 1/7 = 0,1428571428571429, period of this number is (1428571).
1/n (n = 2), 1/2 = 0,5 , so this number doesnt have period.
So i need to wrote recursive algorithm, which print or return period

Comment: So basically given a number, like 17, you calculate 1/17, figure out if that has a repeating sequence of digits in the result, and then you want that sequence? For instance, 1/17 is 0.0588235294117647058823529411764705882352941176470588235294117647 so you would like 5882352941176470 as the result? 0.0**5882352941176470**5882352941176470**5882352941176470**588235294117647

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Exactly!

Comment: Number of issues with your code for starters. `int / int` gives another `int`, not a rational number, so you might want to go for a different type than `int` for your division. However, the best type you have in .NET is `System.Double` and this have limited precision so the result will not have enough digits to actually capture 1/17, it will be `0.058823529411764705`, and then no more digits. You will need a different type. Also, your "detect repeating sequence" code need some work.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen So, when i need to start check duplicate?

Comment: Also, I hope that you put more thought into how to give good examples for questions in the future. You might also edit your question here to give some good examples of the input and the output and **why you expect that output**. It isn't clear why 1/6 should give 6 until you actually spell out 1/6 as 0.1666666666666` and you explain that since 6 is repeating, that's why I want the 6.

Comment: I don't know how to solve your question, I helped you clarify the goal here, so edit your question to make it clearer and hopefully someone else knows how to solve your issue.

Comment: I don't know C#, but this problem can be solved without actually finding a pattern in the decimal digits (which is impossible because of limited precision). You need to compute the euclidean division of 1 by N (not actually 1 but the smallest power of ten above N), get the remainder of this, and recursively compute the euclidean division of it by N (just doing middle-shool division actually). Then find the period in the list of remainders that you generate

Answer (score 0):

find pattern: find one or more digits followed by a period followed by one or more digits, if the digits repeat then capture the group.

```
def repeat(result):    
    pattern=r"\d+\.\d+(\d+)\1"
    matches=re.findall(pattern,result)
    return matches

result=str(1/7)
print(repeat(result))
result=str(1/6)
print(repeat(result)) 
result=str(1/2)
print(repeat(result))
```

output

```
0.14285714285714285->['714285'] (this is more accurate, because it repeats)
0.16666666666666666->['6']
0.5->[]
```